# Combinations - Is there a faster method than manual enumeration?

Tags: combinatorics

**Question:  Papa Your Mommas Pizza Parlor has 6 meat toppings and 7 vegetable toppings from which to select.  The parlor has three different sizes of pizza and two different types of crust.  How many different four-topping pizzas could be ordered?**

To do this problem, I know that there is 4 scenarios:  MMMM, MMMV, MMVV, MVVV, VVVV.  Then I would sum the combinations  of each scenario together:

$\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}*\left[\binom{6}{4}  +  \binom{6}{3}\binom{7}{1}  +  \binom{6}{2}\binom{7}{2} + \binom{6}{1}\binom{7}{3} + \binom{7}{4}\right]=4,290$

My question:  Is it possible to find all combinations (MMMM, MMMV, MMVV, MVVV, VVVV) efficiently or with some type of formula rather than enumerating it manually as I did?

Thank you!  I appreciate your help.

Comment: You seem to be missing $\binom{6}{1}\binom{7}{3}$ in your sum.

Comment: Fixed it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to distinguish between vegetables and meats. All you are doing is choosing $4$ toppings out of the $13$ available. The sum in your bracket is equal to $\binom{13}{4}$.

Comment: You're right.  It matches.  Thank you EuYu.